# How to use GROUP_CONCAT in Grails with Gorm

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I need to use GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function in Grails, preferably from HQL, but also with criteria is ok.

I have this query:

```
ClickTracking.executeQuery("SELECT pageId, containerId, GROUP_CONCAT(clicks) as click" +
                                            "FROM  ClickTracking " +
                                            "WHERE pageId =  ? " +
                                            "GROUP BY containerId ", [pageId])
```

This is not working because HQL is not knowing about GROUP_CONCAT because is DB specific. I am ok to tie my project with MySQL, so I tried to add this in BootStrap.groovy:

```
Configuration conf = grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean("&sessionFactory").configuration;
conf.addSqlFunction("GROUP_CONCAT", new StandardSQLFunction("GROUP_CONCAT", new StringType()));
```

No luck.

Then I tried to subclass the dialect and use it:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction
import org.hibernate.Hibernate

class ExtendedMySqlDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

public ExtendedMySqlDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction("GROUP_CONCAT", new StandardSQLFunction("GROUP_CONCAT", Hibernate.STRING));

}
```

}

and in DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect = "ExtendedMySqlDialect"
logSql = true
```

}

Still no luck. I get:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'GROUP_CONCAT' {originalText=GROUP_CONCAT}
    -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       -[DOT] DotNode: 'clicktrack0_.clicks' {propertyName=clicks,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=clicks,path={synthetic-alias}.clicks,tableAlias=clicktrack0_,className=com.ui.gorm.ClickTracking,classAlias=null}
          +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}
          -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'clicks' {originalText=clicks}
. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 -[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'GROUP_CONCAT' {originalText=GROUP_CONCAT}
    -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       -[DOT] DotNode: 'clicktrack0_.clicks' {propertyName=clicks,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=clicks,path={synthetic-alias}.clicks,tableAlias=clicktrack0_,className=com.ui.gorm.ClickTracking,classAlias=null}
          +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}
          -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'clicks' {originalText=clicks}

```
Line | Method
```

->>  156 | initializeExplicitSelectClause  in org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause

If I set a breakpoint and I look in grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean("&sessionFactory").configuration I can find there a property named sqlFuncions and GROUP_COCNAT is there.

I did some debugging and I ended up in SelectExpressionList.java in this code:

```
public SelectExpression[] collectSelectExpressions() {
    // Get the first child to be considered.  Sub-classes may do this differently in order to skip nodes that
    // are not select expressions (e.g. DISTINCT).
    AST firstChild = getFirstSelectExpression();
    AST parent = this;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList( parent.getNumberOfChildren() );
    for ( AST n = firstChild; n != null; n = n.getNextSibling() ) {
        if ( n instanceof SelectExpression ) {
            list.add( n );
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected AST: " + n.getClass().getName() + " " + new ASTPrinter( SqlTokenTypes.class ).showAsString( n, "" ) );
        }
    }
    return ( SelectExpression[] ) list.toArray( new SelectExpression[list.size()] );
}
```

Seems that n=n.getNextSibbling() is somehow messing up with group_concat, but this is strange because that is from antlr package.

Anyway, I am stuck and I am curious how can I use group_concat (or any other db specific functions in grails with gorm). I am using grails 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Yourdomain.withSession{ session ->  
   session.createSQLQuery(yourQueryWithGroup_concat).setLong(yourParameterName,yourParameterValue).list()  
}
```